# Spring Bean Constructor load From Other bean using List from Constants

Tags: java, spring, list, inversion-of-control

I have a class bean with a constructor like this

```
public Test(final Integer c01,final List<Students>c02){this.c01 = c01;this.c02 = c02;return;}
```

The students comes from another bean which has a method which takes care of retrieving from Database i have a bean declaration like this

```
<constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.Integer" value='13'/>         
<constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.List" value="#{myDAO.loadStudents(#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(T(Constants).HOLIDAY,T(Constants).OUT_OF_OFFICE,T(Constants).SICK_LEAVE)})}"/>
```

The method has a signature like this

```
public List<Student>loadStudents(final List<String>filters){}
```

I will try to explain i need to populate the 2 index of the constructor with a List which i need to retrieve from DB from another bean which is pass a List which i have a Constants in a static manner of course this could be easy solved using this signature only Java

```
new Test(13,Arrays.asList(Constants.HOLIDAY,Constants.OUT_OF_OFFICE,Constant.SICK_LEAVE));
```

But when i have my XML Spring configuration file a error is thrown something like

```
Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

What's is wrong with this code i am not very good using spring

```
 <constructor-arg index="1" type="java.util.List" value="#{myDAO.loadStudents(#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(T(Constants).HOLIDAY,T(Constants).OUT_OF_OFFICE,T(Constants).SICK_LEAVE)})}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SpEL expression is too complex :-)
I would suggest you use Spring Java config and write out what you are trying to do in plain Java code.

As an aside, I have (strong) architectural doubts about reading a database from your Spring configuration. But that's not what the question is about, so I'll try to ignore that :-)